# Focus in input field, on other event

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="inp" type="text" value="asd"  />
</form>

<div id="button">
    button
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    $("#inp").focus();
});
```

DEMO:
     http://jsfiddle.net/YgZx8/1/

If click on `button`, the above code just `selects` (and not happens `focusing`)  the text in input field. this happens in safari and chrome, correctly works in opera and firefox.

Question: how to make input `focusing`  in chrome and safari also ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to focus it _without_ selecting it or something?

Comment: @ BenjaminGruenbaum -- Yes, I need that just focus mouse pointer into input, without text selecting

Comment: @Zenith -- May we have different browser version...

Comment: @OTARIKI Nope, you are right, I was mistaken (I haven't woken up properly yet it seems haha). Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YgZx8/10/

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
   $('#inp').focus().val($('#inp').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    $("#inp")[0].selectionStart = $("#inp")[0].selectionEnd = $('#inp').val().length;
});
```